# python assert for lists of floats

Tags: python, assert

using assert to compare lists of floats seems to work straight out of the box as it were - does anyone know what goes on behind the scenes, e.g. what is the value of EPSILON?

As a C programmer this is all making me feel uneasy... I would have thought maybe the assert would just be comparing pointers but it does seem to be doing something sensible:

```
a = [1.0,2.0]
b = [1.0,2.0]
c = [1.0,2.01]
d = [1.0, 2.0000000000000001]


assert a==b # ok
assert a==c # no go
assert a==d # ok
```

Comment: what does this have to do with assert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not assert that is comparing the lists of floats, it's the `==` operator (or `operator.eq`). `list.__eq__` is just deferring to the `__eq__` of its items. `float.__eq__` isn't doing a pointer/identity comparison, it's doing a value comparison, but it's not using any kind of epsilon - two floats will only compare equal if they represent exactly the same value.

This is almost certainly not what you want, for the reasons discussed [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: ahhh - I see, great explanation

Answer (score 7):

Maybe slightly off-topic, but you don't give much context in your question.

In the various unit testing machineries available (including the `unittest` module from the Python standard library), you will find a `TestCase` method called `assertAlmostEqual(v1, v2, tol)` which you can use to write tests about floating point results of function / method calls. If your function / method returns a list of floats, then it is quite easy to define a new `TestCase` method:

```
def assertListAlmostEqual(self, list1, list2, tol):
    self.assertEqual(len(list1), len(list2))
    for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
         self.assertAlmostEqual(a, b, tol)
```

(work required to provide nice error messages in test reports is left as an exercice to the reader)

Comment: you're spot on - I am in the process of figuring out how to write unit tests in python

Answer (score 5):

Comparing lists in python with `==` compares its elements one after another. If you want to test whether it is the same list, use `is`:

```
>>> a == b
True

>>> a is b
False

>>> e = a
>>> a is e
True
```

In your example, `a == b` because:

```
>>> 2.0 == 2.0000000000000001
True
```

Read more about [floating point arithmetics](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: Python's epsilon value is set to 17 significant digits, by the way: removing one zero from this comparison will make them different (compare-wise).

Comment: @Hiett: yes - Composite Python types like Dictionary, lists and others do have an overriden comparison operator that recursively compares each element.

Answer (score 3):

Talking about asserts specifically, an option is to go for numpy testing framework with the highly convenient function:

```
import numpy as np
np.testing.assert_almost_equal([1.0001, 2.], [1., 2.], decimal=3)
# OK
np.testing.assert_almost_equal([1.0001, 2.], [1., 2.], decimal=6)
# NOT OK
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with asserts, not sure why you involve them. It's just an expression that includes a comparison of two lists, the fact that the result of the expression is then used in an assert doesn't matter.

And, you should probably read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to learn more about precision with floating-point.